# ggplot2: combined bar and line chart alignment

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to chart one variable using bars and another using lines in a single plot.
Here's a minimal example:

```
df <- data.frame(
   Pct_F = c(40,50,60,70,80,90),
   Pct_B = c(50,60,70,80,90,95),
   Time  = c("Pre","Pre","Pre","Post","Post","Post"),
   Variable = c("Var1","Var2","Var3","Var1","Var2","Var3")
)

ggplot(df)+
   geom_bar(aes(x = Variable, y = Pct_F, fill = Time), stat="identity", width = 0.5, position = "dodge")+
   geom_line(aes(x = Variable, y=Pct_B, group = Time, colour=Time), stat="identity", size=2)+
   scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100))+
   coord_flip()+
   labs(title="Test Chart", x= "", y = "Percent", caption = "(Note: Bars refer to Pct_F and lines refer to Pct_B)")
```

Here's the resulting plot:
[bar and line plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAbde.png)

Notice how the line is aligned with the edge of the bars?  How can I get the lines to align with the center of the bars?

Thank you!

Comment: try `position = "dodge"` on your line

Answer (score 2):

You can add it manually with `position_dodge()`. Also, `geom_col` is what you use when you want `geom_bar` with `stat = "identity"`.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(
  Pct_F = c(40,50,60,70,80,90),
  Pct_B = c(50,60,70,80,90,95),
  Time  = c("Pre","Pre","Pre","Post","Post","Post"),
  Variable = c("Var1","Var2","Var3","Var1","Var2","Var3")
)
dodge = position_dodge(0.5)
ggplot(df)+
  geom_col(aes(x = Variable, y = Pct_F, fill = Time), width = 0.5, position = "dodge")+
  geom_line(aes(x = Variable, y=Pct_B, group = Time, colour=Time), stat="identity", size=2, position = dodge)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100))+
  coord_flip()+
  labs(title="Test Chart", x= "", y = "Percent", caption = "(Note: Bars refer to Pct_F and lines refer to Pct_B)")
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you!